# How to create a Dynamic chart in Numbers to change dates based on cell

Tags: macos, numbers

I would like to create a chart in Numbers that can dynamically change date ranges depending on different start and end dates set in start and end cells (or drop downs). This is for the purpose of charting stock prices 1 month, 3 Month, YTD etc. Excel allows for this - does Numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Open help and search for “[Add Interactive Chart](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/interactive-charts-tanc8e2eb44e/mac)” and you’ll get a very good guide on how Numbers supports interactive graphics.